# Large caterpillar with prominent eye-spots and a Morse-code pattern

Tags: species-identification, entomology

I would appreciate any help in identifying this caterpillar.

- Location: Goa, India. Tropical climate
- Currently rainy season. Seen in the morning
- Length: about 5cm, Diameter: about 1cm

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you describe what’s happening in that video? Is the caterpillar being flipped around by a push of air, or is it moving on its own accord (in reaction to a visual stimulus?)?

Comment: @KonradRudolph The caterpillar was flipping on its own, most certainly reacting to the movement of the dog's paws (seen in the corner). The dog spotted it first and was  freaking out and barking at it, though keeping a safe distance.

Comment: This is really cool! Thanks for posting. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This appears to be an [oleander hawk-moth caterpillar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daphnis_nerii) (*Daphnis nerii*) shortly before pupating. Otherwise the caterpillar would be bright green in colour:

> Newly hatched oleander hawk-moth larvae are three to four millimeters in length, bright yellow, and have a black, elongated "horn" on the rear of the body. … As they get older, the larvae become green to brown with a large blue-and-white eyespot near the head and a yellow "horn" on the rear. […] Just before it pupates, the oleander hawk-moth larva becomes browner in colour.